# Android Bitmap ListView

Tags: android, listview

ima trying to add images in my listview but i got this error:

```
You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
```

This the menu layout, menu.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sahovnica"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_Menu_Title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/vh_title" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_Menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView_Menu_Title" >

</ListView>
```

this is the list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_List_Item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my code:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_Menu);

     Bitmap[] images = { decodeImage(R.drawable.igraj), 
                             decodeImage(R.drawable.rezultati),
             decodeImage(R.drawable.postavke),
             decodeImage(R.drawable.pomoc), decodeImage(R.drawable.izlaz)};

     ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Bitmap>(this, R.layout.list_item,
                                                                     images);

     list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private Bitmap decodeImage(int res) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),res);               
    return bitmap;      
}

}
```

I dont know what would it mean (the error) because i tryed to put some strings in ArrayAdapter and put in list_item.xml a TextView as an item and it still didnt worked, but i cannot figure why.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`ArrayAdapter` Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html):

> By default this class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView. If you want to use a more complex layout, use the constructors that also takes a field id. That field id should reference a TextView in the larger layout resource.
>
> [...]
>
> To use something other than TextViews for the array display, for instance, ImageViews, or to have some of data besides toString() results fill the views, override getView(int, View, ViewGroup) to return the type of view you want.

You need to either create your own `BaseAdapter` implementation, or create your own `ArrayAdapter` subclass and override `getView()`.

A simple `getView()` that uses images might look something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflateR.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) :

```
A concrete BaseAdapter .......to use a more complex layout, use the constructors that also takes a field id. That field id should reference a TextView in the larger layout resource.
```

As you can see, you're required to have in a `TextView` in the layout file that R.layout.list_item references. You only have a `ImageView` in that layout.

For more complex views (that are not limited to `TextView`'s, I suggest you use your own implementation of [`BaseAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the constructor's of ArrayAdapter

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

As others have suggested use a CustomAdapter

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_Menu);
    String[] a ={"hi","bye"};
    Bitmap[] images = { decodeImage(R.drawable.igraj), 
                         decodeImage(R.drawable.rezultati),
                         decodeImage(R.drawable.postavke),
                         decodeImage(R.drawable.pomoc),              
                         decodeImage(R.drawable.izlaz)
                       };
     CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(images);
     list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private Bitmap decodeImage(int res) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),res);               
    return bitmap;      
}
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Bitmap images[]; 
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public CustomAdapter(Bitmap[] Images)
    {
        images=Images;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(MenuActivity.this);

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return images.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder.iv= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_List_Item);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.iv.setImageBitmap(images[position]);
        return convertView;
    }

}
class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView iv;
}
}
```